# MapKit Memory Leaks. No Idea Why

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, memory-management, memory-leaks

I am running the leaks tool in instruments on a device. I am getting leaks of MKReverseGeocoder, MKReverseGeocoderInternal, and NSCFString (Points to -(void)reverseGeocoder: didFindPlacemark). I have been working on these leaks for over 2 days and cannot find a solution. If anyone can point me in the right direction I would be very gracious.

.H

```
@interface ReviewViewController : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate, MKReverseGeocoderDelegate,MKAnnotation > {
    IBOutlet UIImageView *_changingStationIV;
    IBOutlet UIImageView *_feedingAreaIV;
    IBOutlet UIImageView *_highChairIV;
    IBOutlet MKMapView *_mapView;
    MKReverseGeocoder *_reverseGeocoder;
    SGFeature *_place;
    MKPlacemark *_loc;

}

@property(nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UIImageView *changingStationIV;
@property(nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UIImageView *feedingAreaIV;
@property(nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UIImageView *highChairIV;
@property(nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;
@property(nonatomic,retain) MKReverseGeocoder *reverseGeocoder;
@property(nonatomic,retain) SGFeature *place;
@property(nonatomic,retain) MKPlacemark *loc;

@end
```

.M

```
        @implementation ReviewViewController
     @synthesize changingStationIV=_changingStationIV,feedingAreaIV=_feedingAreaIV, highChairIV= _highChairIV, reverseGeocoder= _reverseGeocoder, mapView=_mapView,loc=_loc,coordinate=_coordinate,place=_place;

     // Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        NSLog(@"ViewDidLoad");

    NSLog(@"CURRENT PLACE %@",  [[self.place asDictionary] description]);

    NSDictionary *props = [self.place properties];

    self.title = [props objectForKey:@"name"];

    NSLog(@"changingStation: %@", [props objectForKey:@"changingStation"]);

    NSLog(@"feedingArea: %@", [props objectForKey:@"feedingArea"]);

    NSLog(@"highChair: %@", [props objectForKey:@"highChair"]);

    if ([[props objectForKey:@"changingStation"] boolValue]==YES) {
        self.changingStationIV.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"check.png"];
    }else {
        self.changingStationIV.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"x.png"];
    }
    if ( [[props objectForKey:@"feedingArea"] boolValue]==YES) {
        self.feedingAreaIV.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"check.png"];
    }else {
        self.feedingAreaIV.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"x.png"];
    }
    if ( [[props objectForKey:@"highChair"] boolValue]==YES) {
        self.highChairIV.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"check.png"];
    }else {
        self.highChairIV.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"x.png"];
    }

    SGPoint *point = (SGPoint*)[self.place geometry];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D locCoord = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(point.latitude, point.longitude);
    NSDictionary *locDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[props objectForKey:@"name"] forKey:@"Country"];
    self.loc = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithCoordinate:locCoord addressDictionary:locDict];
    [self.mapView addAnnotation:self.loc];


    MKUserLocation *userLocation = self.mapView.userLocation;
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = userLocation.location.coordinate;
    [self.mapView setCenterCoordinate:coord animated:YES];

    MKCoordinateRegion region;
    MKCoordinateSpan span;
    region.center = locCoord;
    span.latitudeDelta =0.005334;
    span.longitudeDelta = 0.011834;
    region.span = span;

    [self.mapView setCenterCoordinate:locCoord animated:YES];
    [self.mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];


        self.reverseGeocoder = [[MKReverseGeocoder alloc] initWithCoordinate:locCoord];
        self.reverseGeocoder.delegate = self;
            [self.reverseGeocoder start];



    }


        -(void)reverseGeocoder:(MKReverseGeocoder *)geocoder didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{

        }

        -(void)reverseGeocoder:(MKReverseGeocoder *)geocoder didFindPlacemark:(MKPlacemark *)placemark{

                self.mapView.userLocation.title = placemark.title;

        }   


        - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
            // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
            [su

per didReceiveMemoryWarning];

        // Release any cached data, images, etc. that aren't in use.
    }

    - (void)viewDidUnload {
        [super viewDidUnload];
        // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
        // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;

    NSLog(@"ViewDidUnload");


        self.changingStationIV =nil;
        self.feedingAreaIV=nil;
        self.highChairIV=nil;
        self.reverseGeocoder=nil;
        self.place=nil;
        self.loc=nil;


    }


    - (void)dealloc {

        NSLog(@"Review-Dealloc");


        self.reverseGeocoder=nil;
        self.mapView=nil;
        self.changingStationIV =nil;
        self.feedingAreaIV=nil;
        self.highChairIV=nil;
        self.place=nil;
        self.loc=nil;


        [super dealloc];

    }


    @end
```

Comment: I find Mapkit leaking all over the place as well - even if you're implementing a very basic out-of-the-box map

Comment: could you also post the header file so we can see how properties have been declared?

Comment: (nonatomic,retain) header coming...

Comment: are you also retaining the delegate? I would suggest setting the delegate to assign, so that there isn't a retain cycle.

Comment: can you explain further? I am confused.. I have added self.mapView.delegate = self;

Comment: excuse me, I misread your code, the delegate is fine. as OMZ said, you should be autoreleasing MKReverseGeocoder, and also MKPlacemark, have you run build and analyse in Xcode? that will point out a large amount of memory management issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are certainly leaking memory here:

```
    self.loc = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithCoordinate:locCoord 
                                     addressDictionary:locDict];
```

Since you have defined `loc` as a `retain` property, assigning to it will call `retaing` on the argument, and you'll end up with a `MKPlacemark` that ware retained and never released.

I would change that line as follows:

```
    self.loc = [[[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithCoordinate:locCoord 
                                     addressDictionary:locDict] autorelease];
```

Also, check carefullly your code for this pattern, since as @omz suggests, you are doing it also when assigning to `reverseGeocoder`.

Comment: Thanks it is a bad pattern in my code. Thanks for pointing it out, is there anywhere I can learn more about why this is a leak? I am still having a hard time getting my head around it...

Comment: I would start here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/index.html

Answer (score 2):

In your `viewDidLoad` method, you set the `reverseGeocoder` property like this:

```
self.reverseGeocoder = [[MKReverseGeocoder alloc] initWithCoordinate:locCoord];
```

This leaks, because the property setter already retains the object. You need to release or autorelease the `MKReverseGeocoder` instance after setting the property, e.g.:

```
self.reverseGeocoder = [[[MKReverseGeocoder alloc] initWithCoordinate:locCoord] autorelease];
```

Comment: [self.reverseGeocoder release] will do? I am still confused on why I am releasing the property

Comment: You have declared your property as retained (see header), so `self.reverseGeocoder = ...` will automatically send a `retain` to the object you're using as the property. As you need to balance every `alloc-init` or `retain` with a corresponding `release` or `autorelease`, you're missing one `release`.